# "Sometimes I feel I will burst from the inside"

Tags: idioms

I encountered this phrase in a questionnaire:

> Sometimes I feel I will burst from the inside

I do have a vague idea of what this might mean. But is it something that a native speaker would say? And if yes, what would they feel like when saying that?

Comment: It's a rather strange thing to say, since "bursting" ***always*** implies material going ***from** the inside **to** the outside*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point. "It burst from the outside" would seem unlikely. But then, we often say things that are redundant and repetitious. "I fell down." As opposed to falling up? "We planned the trip in advance." As opposed to planning after the trip was over? Etc.

Comment: @Jay: Well, it's certainly quite normal to speak of things or people *bursting **in*** and *bursting **out***, but in that latter case I can't easily imagine a context where you might go the whole hog and say something *burst out **from the inside***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully the person is not speaking literally. (I've seen some science fiction movies where this happens.) Exactly what it means depends on context. I'd expect either:

(a) The speaker feels like his stomach is bloated. Perhaps he has eaten way too much or has eaten something that is making him sick.

(b) The speaker is filled with emotion. This could be positive or negative. Like if her boyfriend just proposed, a girl might say, "Oh, I'm so filled with happiness, I feel I could just burst." Or at the other extreme if someone's child just died, they might say, "Oh, I am so filled with grief, I feel I will just burst."

Comment: Yeah, unless it was a medical questionnaire, it almost certainly was referring to "b" -- strong feelings of emotion that are difficult to contain.

Comment: Thank you! This was a psycho questionnaire about weird thoughts and feelings that some people might sometimes have - so I think they refer to explosive emotions rather than eating oneself sick.